# [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory() include directory in archive

Tags: powershell, dotnetzip

I need to compress and extract some zip files with a rather large source, often 30GB or more, so I can't use the native PowerShell cmdlets. I am looking at using `[IO.Compression.ZipFile]` static methods, and liking the fact that it works with big source folders, and works faster in general. But I am running into one issue. I want to include the source folder IN the archive, like `Compress-Archive` does

```
$sourcePath = '\\px\Rollouts\ADSK\2023\Revit_2023\Deployment\Revit_2023'
Compress-Archive -Path:$sourcePath -DestinationPath:$zipPath
```

the `Revit_2023` folder is part of the archive, while with

```
[IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($sourcePath, $zipPath)
```

only the CONTENTS of the `Revit_2023` folder is archived. When extracting I could create a folder with the name of the Zip file as the folder name and extract to that, but I can imagine a scenario where I really want the Zip file named differently, perhaps with a date or something. But in looking at the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile?view=net-7.0) it looks like this behavior is the only option for a simple implementation, and doing what I want to do is going to require managing entries myself. And even that I am not sure about, since it looks like entries are files only? Am I misunderstanding here, and there is an option to include the source folder? I sure would prefer to have a simple solution AND the source folder name in the archive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overloads of the method are:

```
static void CreateFromDirectory(string sourceDirectoryName, string destinationArchiveFileName)
static void CreateFromDirectory(string sourceDirectoryName, string destinationArchiveFileName, System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel compressionLevel, bool includeBaseDirectory)
static void CreateFromDirectory(string sourceDirectoryName, string destinationArchiveFileName, System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel compressionLevel, bool includeBaseDirectory, System.Text.Encoding entryNameEncoding)
```

So the command would be:

```
[IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($sourcePath, $zipPath, [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Optimal, $true)
```

You could pick different CompressionLevel, but you can't skip it when also using includeBaseDirectory flag.

Comment: Aha! I will eventually get my head around some of these .NET subtleties. Thanks!

Comment: And now to implement both, since I can also see a scenario where my source path will include a wildcard and I don't want to include the source folder.